Failure in Compiling contract in Remix with ZK sync plugin
I have been trying to compile my contract in Remix with Zk Sync Plugin. The solidity version i applied was 0.8.24; I even tried switching between different solidity versions but the current zk sync version doesnt seem to compile anything. It shows this error.

I tried checking in my code too but it looks fine too.
This is my complete code
Code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.24; //solidity versions

contract SimpleStorage {
 uint256 public FN; //0 ( an internal variable) 

uint256 [] listofRNs; 
struct Person {
    uint256 FNN;
    string name;
}
 Person [] public listofFriends; //a null list ( a Public list of Friends Array)

 mapping (string => uint256) public PTFN;
 
 function store(uint256 _FN) public{FN=_FN;} //update the FN

 function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {return FN;} // retrieve the FN
 function AddFriends (string memory _name, uint256 _FNN) public {listofFriends.push(Person(_FNN, _name));
 PTFN[_name]=_FNN; // add people to both our list and mapping
}
 


The line at the end PTFN[_name]=_FNN; is outside a function. Probably you need to fix that
